# Select multiple categories by checkbox, and show articles belonging to those categories

Tags: wordpress

I could prepare this code by great help of somebody in stack overflow.

**HTML Code**

```
<form class="cat-search" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">
    <input type="checkbox" value="SlugA" id="cat0" class="cats2"/><label for="cat0">Category1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="SlugB" id="cat1" class="cats2"/><label for="cat1">Category2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="SlugC" id="cat2" class="cats2"/><label for="cat2">Category3</label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="SlugD" id="cat3" class="cats2"/><label for="cat3">Category4</label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="SlugE" id="cat4" class="cats2"/><label for="cat4">Category5</label>
    <input type="hidden" id="cat2" name="category" />
    <input type="submit" class="cat-search" value="search" />
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script>
$(function(){
$('body').on('click', '.cats2', function() {
    var cats = $('.cats2:checked').map( function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get().join("+");
    $('#cat2').val( cats );
});
});
</script>
```

As a result, I have URL like this when I select Category1 and Category2

**my domein/?category=SlugA%2bSlugB**

`"%2" implies "+" in above case`.

Now, I like to change above URL to below one to show all articles belonging to Category1 and Category2.

**my domein/category/slugA+slugB**

Is it possible to change url like this?

Answer (score 0):

I could solve above my issue by search and filter plugin.  Thank you.